# Integrating along a branch cut

Tags: contour-integration, branch-cuts

What contour would one use to integrate the following equation?

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$ where $-1 < a <3 $ and $x^a= e^{aln(x)}$

Answer (score 0):

Using integration by parts and the integral in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216),
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^a}{(1+x^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{\frac{a-1}2}}{(1+x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac12\int_0^\infty x^{\frac{a-1}2}\,\mathrm{d}\frac1{1+x}\\
&=\frac{a-1}4\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{\frac{a-3}2}}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\pi\,\frac{a-1}4\,\csc\left(\pi\frac{a-1}2\right)\\[3pt]
&=\pi\,\frac{1-a}4\,\sec\left(\pi\frac a2\right)
\end{align}
$$
So we can use the contour used in that answer.

Comment: The question asked about the appropriate contour

Comment: @jim: I have referenced [another answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!